# How to display description of method parameter?

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense

I have a method documented like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Execute a call request to the endpoint specified
/// </summary>
/// <param name="URI">Endpoint of API</param>

public string Call()
{
    return null;
}
```

But when I put the mouse over `Call`, I can't see the `URI` param description, only the `Call` method description. I also tried pressing `ctrl + shift + space` but nothing happens. An image example:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add a parameter to the function an then mouse-over the parameter in order to see the description.
For example:

```
/// <summary>
/// Execute a call request to the endpoint specified
/// </summary>
/// <param name="uri">Endpoint of API</param>

public string Call(string uri)
{
    return null;
}
```

[demo image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sugjJ.png)

Comment: Yes I missing this in the example but.. it's not the point. I understand now that I can see the description of the parameter only on the function, but if I put mouse over on another class I see only the method description.

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can go to Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard or Default Keyboard Shortcuts in Visual Studio, you can then search for commands and see what is assigned to that (and remap).